# Run if condition if data not exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please check code bellow. I am having wrong entity query i think. check inside second if condition and marked entity query. My goal is save data if this CategoryID not available. But when i run it on debug i can see simply the if condition being skipped however my database not has any data so it should be empty and run if inside codes. I think i am doing something wrong with entity query which marked bellow. Any idea?

> ctx.Level1Cats.Any(x => x.Level1CatId != item.CategoryID.ToString())

```
foreach (CategoryType item in categories)
{
    if (item.CategoryLevel == 1)
    {
        if (ctx.Level1Cats.Any(x => x.Level1CatId != item.CategoryID.ToString()))
        {
            CatLevel1.Level1CatId = item.CategoryID;
            CatLevel1.Name = item.CategoryName;
            ctx.Level1Cats.Add(CatLevel1);
            //ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        else if (ctx.Level1Cats.Any(x => x.Level1CatId == item.CategoryID.ToString()))
        {
            CatLevel1.Level1CatId = item.CategoryID;
            CatLevel1.Name = item.CategoryName;
            ctx.Entry(CatLevel1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why item.CategoryID is ToString()? ID should be number isnt it?

Comment: Yes my database also same ID is not int its string @LiakatHossain

Comment: Given `ctx.Level1Cats` contains more than one entry, then I'd expect that `if` to *always* be true. It could only possibly be false if ctx.Level1Cats has exactly one entry and item.CategoryID *is* the ID of that one entry ...

Comment: Does ctx.Level1Cats have any entries or is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem using your existing code, you can use `All` inside of the `if` and then just use a standard `else` without the additional check:

```
if (ctx.Level1Cats.All(x => x.Level1CatId != item.CategoryID.ToString()))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

This will go into your `if` block if `item.CategoryID` does not exist (note that `All` returns true if the list itself is empty). Otherwise, your else will be used instead.

Another option would be to keep the `Any` but invert the logic:

```
if (ctx.Level1Cats.Any(x => x.Level1CatId == item.CategoryID.ToString()))
{
    // UPDATE.
}
else
{
    // ADD.
}
```

In this case, if any of the items matches the `item.CategoryID`, you will peform your update. Otherwise, it'll be the `Add`.

In my experience, the second option shown is more common, where you're looking specifically to find the item of interest and then reacting accordingly.